# array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given Laravel 8 form validation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 as a backend to my SPA front-end, I've done countless number of validation features before and have never bumped into this strange issue with the validator, I'm getting:

> array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given

And the main error logged is:

```
[2022-06-27 19:44:11] local.ERROR: array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given at C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Desktop\\web-projects\\domain-monitor\\domain-monitor-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationRuleParser.php:92)
```

What am I missing from my function?

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Request $request, $uuid)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'use_filters' => `boolean`
    ]);
    
    $validator->sometimes('period', 'integer|in:24,48,72,168,720,1440', function ($input) {
        return $input->use_filters == true;
    });
    
    $validator->sometimes('mode', 'string|in:exact,average', function ($input) {
        return $input->use_filters == true;
    });
    
    $validator->sometimes('device', 'string|in:mobile,desktop', function ($input) {
        return $input->use_filters == true;
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'It looks like you missed something',
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ], 400);
    }

    $monitor = Monitor::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                      ->where('uuid', $uuid)
                      ->first();

    if (!$monitor) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'We can\'t find this monitor'
        ], 404);
    }

    // if in filtering mode
    if ($request->boolean('use_filters')) {
        $period = $request->input('period') ?? 24;
        $mode = $request->input('mode') ?? 'average';
        $device = $request->input('device') ?? 'desktop';



        if (intval($period) > 168 && !Auth::user()->is_subscribed) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => "You must upgrade your account to the Pro subscription to view more historical data."
            ], 400);
        }

        // add our uptime checks to our monitor
        try {
            if ($monitor) {
                $monitor['charts'] = $this->getCharts($monitor, $period, $mode, $device);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Your monitor',
        'monitor' => $monitor
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full trace that you can post?

Comment: Why are you using backtick `\`` instead of apostrophe `'` on `'use_filters' => \`boolean\``